# Handling dynamic content

Tags: ajax

I would like to be able retrieve all entries based on a category selected in a drop down list. From a UX perspective, I would like this to be as seamless as possible and not have to do full page refresh. Is this something I should build using the ElementAPI or is there better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this would be to use [ElementAPI](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI), however you could create an alternative template with a JSON header coupled with a route.